# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "FBReactNativeSpec" while pod install

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

```
  In Podfile:
    FBReactNativeSpec (from `../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec`)

Specs satisfying the `FBReactNativeSpec (from `../node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

System M1 air
react-native version 0.63

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to update the `platform` targeted within your `Podfile`.
e.g. `platform :ios, '13.0'`